# No value given for one or more required parameters c#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

An error appear when i want to execute my SQL statement in C# application, which it's:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.

I'm using c# with MS access database.
This is my code:

```
string string2 = "";

if (radButton2 != null)
{
     string2 = " and signaal1.info='" + radButton2.Text + "' ";
}
else
     string2 = " and signaal1.info='0' ";
if (radButton3 != null)
{
     string2 += " and situation.info='" + radButton3.Text + "' ";
}
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT actionz.info, relationz.id AS actionz FROM ((((relationz LEFT OUTER JOIN conditions ON relationz.conditions_id = conditions.id) LEFT OUTER JOIN situation ON relationz.situation_id = situation.id) LEFT OUTER JOIN car_type ON relationz.car_id = car_type.id) LEFT OUTER JOIN actionz ON relationz.action_id = actionz.id) LEFT OUTER JOIN signal AS signaal1 ON relationz.signal_id = signaal1.id where car_type.info='" + radButton1.Text + "' " + string2 + "  ORDER BY conditions.id ASC", objConn);
//cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@car_type", radButton1.Text);

OleDbDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: What is your `cmd` looks like when you add your string values? Just before `OleDbDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();` line? Debug your code and tell us. And you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: You should debug the actual query string and then you can see what wrong with your query.

Comment: i make it as a note !, i added manually:
car_type.info=' " + radButton1.Text + " ' "

Comment: is it always recommended to create you sql statement first, then pass it into some functions. That way you can easily log the sql statement and see if it is actually a valid statement.

Answer (score 0):

Typo:

```
" ...info='" + radButton1.Text + "' " + string2 + "  ORDER BY ..."
```

should be

```
" ...info='" + radButton1.Text + string2 + "'  ORDER BY ..."
```

or if you need the space between the values:

```
" ...info='" + radButton1.Text + " " + string2 + "'  ORDER BY ..."
```

Open to Injection though as mentioned.

Comment: No, how like that !! "info='" + radButton1.Text + string2 + "'  ORDER BY" !
i added the single quotation before in the if statement !

Comment: the `"` before info is just so that it displays properly in stack overflow. No need for exclaimation marks here my friend.

Comment: The single quotations are the problem. Especially here: `string2 = " and signaal1.info='0' ";` You need to use parameterized queries.

Comment: i deleted all this part and i removed " + string2 + "  part, same error appear

Comment: Try this query string. Enter a value you would expect to be in the **care_type.info** column where I have **EnterSomeValueHere**. `"SELECT actionz.info, relationz.id AS actionz FROM ((((relationz LEFT OUTER JOIN conditions ON relationz.conditions_id = conditions.id) LEFT OUTER JOIN situation ON relationz.situation_id = situation.id) LEFT OUTER JOIN car_type ON relationz.car_id = car_type.id) LEFT OUTER JOIN actionz ON relationz.action_id = actionz.id) LEFT OUTER JOIN signal AS signaal1 ON relationz.signal_id = signaal1.id where car_type.info='EnterSomeValueHere' ORDER BY conditions.id ASC"`